# Fastest algorithm to check collection of words in phone digit

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

For example I have an array ['bab', 'col', 'stro'] ...

```
IN     OUT
222    bab
7876   stro
999    <empty>        no match
```

Is there any algorithm to solve this better than **O(n^2)**?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'check'. Do you look for a name related to a number or other way round? In both cases you can use a Map (HashMap) that should allow you each lookup in about O(1) time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

preprocess your list into a translation table, with each word keyed to its numerical equivalent.  This gives you an easy look-up for the search.

```
dial_num = [
    'a' : 2,
    'b' : 2,
    'c' : 2.
    'd' : 3,
    ...
]
```

Next, translate each of your words:

```
dial_word = [
    222 : 'bab',
    264 : 'col',
    7876 : 'stro'
    ...
]
```

That task is **O(N)** on the array length in characters.
Now, you have a simple search (linear or log) for a given number.  If you want to further pre-process `dial_word` as a hash table, you will have **O(1)** look-up.

Comment: How do you translate each word, how you compare it?

Comment: You get it from the dial_num table which you have to create it by yourself.

Comment: @mysteryfollow: how to translate and how to compare are language-dependent implementation details, not part of the *algorithm*; that algorithm is your question.

Comment: Note that the dial_word may not be a mapping in the case where multiple word strings translate to the same number. A better way would be to use a linked list in this case; or to do iterative search from the code in my answer.

Comment: @Vince: yes, in that case, OP needs to build out the word to an array of compatible words.  Since that wasn't part of the post, I didn't complicate my answer with that detail.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::vector<std::string> words` to represent input.

```
std::vector<std::string> S;
// First convert strings to (string)numbers.
for(auto word in words){
    std::string s;
    for(auto c in word)
        switch (c)
        {
            case 'a':case 'b': case 'c'
            s += '1'; break;
            case 'd':case 'e': case 'f'
            s += '2'; break;
            ...
        }
    S.push_back(s);
}

// Now S has corresponding numbers for each string
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
// Find the number string match on a given input. You can do iteratively search here to find all.
if (S.find(input) == S.end())
    std::cout << "Does not exist" << endl;
else
    std::cout << words[S.find(input) - S.begin()] << endl;
```

This is a simple snippet in C++ and you would be able to convert to any other languages.

Strictly speaking, there does not exist `O(n)` algorithm since it has to depend on the max length of the strings. This algorithm runs in `O(kn)` where `k` is the max length of all strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **TRIE** data Structure for Implementing (each phone name&number entry is one leaf). TRIE is an ordered tree data structure that uses strings as keys.
check this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18033/Phone-Directory-Implementation-Using-TRIE)